# How to get chromium with vaapi on ubuntu 20.10?

Tags: snap, chromium, hardware-acceleration, vaapi, 20.10

is there any way to get chromium with vaapi on ubuntu 20.10?? I've tried snap version from candidate/vaapi channel and it does not work now but it worked about a month or so ago.

gpu: intel hd 620

Comment: I just checked. The chromium package from snap has the option. You can enable it through chrome://flags.

Comment: What options? If you mean chrome://flags/#ignore-gpu-blocklist and chrome://flags/#disable-accelerated-video-decode I have both enabled already. I have also tried "--use-angle=gl" but nothing worked. Does it works for you??

Comment: I forgot something and I apologize. I got my chromium installed from ppa:saiarcot895/chromium-beta. Vaapi worked for me. But I had bunch of problems later on like video not loading. I did not install chromium from snap.

Comment: Then I switched on my other machine to Fedora with the same hardware. Vaapi on their chromium package works without any problem. I did not care enough to go and see if I can use the same patch for fedora and build it myself. Used to do it, but it is a really time-consuming process.

Comment: Just becasue of OCD problems ;-) I looked into Brave and it looks like the have enabled the vaapi patches. I enabled video decode through the flags and intel_gpu_top shows that my gpu doing the decoding of vp9 videos.

Comment: I can confirm on fedora works flawlessly.

This ppa does not work either. As I see there are many bug reports

* https://github.com/saiarcot895/chromium-ubuntu-build/issues/98

* https://github.com/saiarcot895/chromium-ubuntu-build/issues/83

* https://github.com/saiarcot895/chromium-ubuntu-build/issues/91

I give up! I'll probably use fedora and windows for now.

Answer (score 0):

According to this article here:

https://www.linuxuprising.com/2020/12/chromium-and-ungoogled-chromium-web.html

The Chromium Flatpak available on Flathub has VAAPI enabled. I just tested it and it did not work for me though. However maybe it'll work for you. Even if it does not work right now for you, I'd keep an eye on the Flatpak. I left a comment of my experience on their bug tracker here: https://github.com/flathub/org.chromium.Chromium/issues/35

Comment: thank you very much! I'll give it a try :)

Answer (score 0):

If using NVIDIA graphics, I made a GitHub [repository](https://github.com/marioroy/nvidia-acceleration-on-ubuntu) which builds the NVDEC-backend and VDPAU-backend VA-API drivers used by Firefox and Chromium-based browsers. There are install scripts for installing Brave, Ungoogled-Chrome (or) Chromium-Beta with VA-API support, and Google Chrome Stable.

Hardware video decode does not work in Ungoogled-Chrome. Though, working wonderfully in Firefox, Brave, Chromium Beta with VA-API support, and Google Chrome.

The repository was developed and tested on Ubuntu 20.04.4 running Xorg.